# How to dynamically change text of ContentEditable on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

I have string `^aUsername ^bLastName ^cAge`. And I need create one editable element where I can edit that string. But the biggest problem of this input is that this element should color every single letter after marc `^`. So it's should look like this

[image]

I'm currently using library `react-contenteditable` to manage that in React.

```
function getParsedValue(value) {
  let vals = value.split('^').slice(1);
  let text = "";

  if (vals) {
    vals.map((val, i) => {
      text = text + `<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold">${val[0]}</span>${val.slice(1)}`;
    })
  } else {
    text = value;
  }
  return text;
}


function MarcInput({ value }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState(marc);

  const handleChanges = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <ContentEditable
        onChange={handleChanges}
        html={getParsedValue(text)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

But now I can't add more string to this input. How to achieve that every word starting from `^` has color and it gonna work for new words by adding text to input

Comment: have you tried with onInput={function(e) {
    console.log("changed!");
  }}